# Changing text color in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I want to write a Greasemonkey script that will change the color of the text on any page while leaving the structure as it is. I would like to change the first 10 visible characters to be red, the next 10 to be blue, the next to be red again and so on.

I see two possible ways of going about this:

1. iterating through every element on the page, checking if it has text that is displayed and changing the text color. I guess this can be done by getting all elements using `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML` and then calling `elements[i].textContent` to get the text but I do not know how to determine if the text is visible or not. This will return the text inside <script> elements and adding color attributes to those elements will break the page.
2. selecting the text on the page with something like `window.getSelection().addRange(WholePage)` but then I don't know of any way of changing the text color.

If you think of any other method please feel free to suggest it.

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you mean by `the first 10 visible characters to be red, the next 10 to be blue, the next to be red again and so on.`

Comment: For example when looking at this page I would like to see something like this (ignoring the top part): "Questions Tags" in red, "Users Badges" blue, "Unanswered Ask Question" red, "Chaning text" in blue, "color in" red, "Greasemonkey" blue, "I want to" red and so on. Nothing changed but the colors. I'll try to post an example somewhere.

Comment: How does that meet the requirement of `every 10 characters`?

Comment: Here is the link: [http://i.imgur.com/DE4fi6d.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/DE4fi6d.jpg) My first comment wasn't respecting the 10 characters mentioned in the question, I was trying to make things a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (use jQuery).

```
$('p, li').each(function(){
     var length = $(this).text().length;
     var newStr = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < length; i+=20) {
         newStr += '<span style="color:red">' + $(this).text().substring(i, i + 10) + '</span>';
         newStr += '<span style="color:blue">' + $(this).text().substring(i + 10, i + 20) + '</span>';
     }

     $(this).html(newStr);
});
```

Comment: Not all text is in paragraphs or lists. Also, you don't need jQuery for a task like this. Clever solution, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does mess up the existing formatting though. I've added a TD to the p and li and the result of the script running on the current page can be seen here: [http://i.imgur.com/ucC3qL3.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/ucC3qL3.jpg)

Comment: @miai You need to take into account nested tags (and the text within those tags).  This disregards inner tags.  But it's a start.

Comment: Yes, you right. The inner tags get overwritten. Thanks again for the answer.